Probability density function for at least one of two random variables being within a certain bracket.
Consider two random variables $X_A$ and $X_B$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Each of them has a probability density function $p_i(x)$ for $i = A, B$. By definition:
$$p_i(x)dx = P(X_i \in [x, x+dx])$$
Then, this probability I'm trying to compute should be:
$$P(\text{At least one in }[x, x+dx]) = 1 - (1-p_A(x)dx)(1-p_B(x)dx) = (p_A(x)+p_B(x))dx-p_A(x)p_B(x)(dx)^2$$
My issue here is that I'm trying to make sense of this as another p.d.f. However, the second order term makes it impossible to treat like so, at least not trivially. How can I make sense of this? Is there any  way to define a p.d.f. to solve this?
